# Two ArrayLists starting with the same data

Tags: java, select, arraylist, comparison

Would you like to help me on the following:

Created 3 ArrayLists with defined values and an ArrayList that will receive the value of a select in the database. Then I want to compare the value of ArrayList called database with ArrayLists with defined values that I created.

Is giving error because the ArrayList called NIVELACESSOOper has only data: "Operacional" and ArrayList called NIVELACESSOOperFin has 2 data that are "Operacional" and "Financeiro" and when I try to run the ArrayList called NIVELACESSOOperFin is running the NIVELACESSOOper because both begin with the data "Operacional "... even I using .containsAll the comparison went wrong because it is comparing the first data and not the whole of the ArrayList called NIVELACESSOOperFin. Continues only comparing the first data.

I would love to have your support !!!

```
    List NIVELACESSOOper; {

    NIVELACESSOOper = new ArrayList();
    NIVELACESSOOper.add("Operacional");
}

List NIVELACESSOOperFin; {

    NIVELACESSOOperFin = new ArrayList();
    NIVELACESSOOperFin.add("Operacional");
    NIVELACESSOOperFin.add("Financeiro");
}

List NIVELACESSOAdmFinOper; {

    NIVELACESSOAdmFinOper = new ArrayList();
    NIVELACESSOAdmFinOper.add("Administrador");
    NIVELACESSOAdmFinOper.add("Financeiro");
    NIVELACESSOAdmFinOper.add("Operacional");
}


public void Logar() {

    List result = new ArrayList();

    String sql = "SELECT usuario_login, senha_login, nome_login, nivelAcesso FROM nivelAcessoSistema NATURAL JOIN login WHERE usuario_login = ? AND senha_login = ?";

    try {

        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, txtUsuario.getText()); //Campo do usuário
        pst.setString(2, txtSenha.getText()); //Campo da senha

        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) { //Se existe registro no banco de dados com os dados informados na tela de login...

            String nivelAcesso = rs.getString("nivelAcesso"); //Comparando valor de atríbuto "nivelAcesso" do banco de dados

            result.add(nivelAcesso);

            if (result.containsAll(NIVELACESSOOper)) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter the screen Operacional");
            }

            else if(result.containsAll(NIVELACESSOOperFin)) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter the screen Operacional - Financeiro");
            }

            else if (result.containsAll(NIVELACESSOAdmFinOper)) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter the screen Operacional - Financeiro - Administrativo");
            }
```

Comment: is it giving  this result : ""Enter the screen Operacional" only ? and did you print : nivelAcesso  ?

Comment: When I have run the NIVELACESSOOperFin is running NIVELACESSOOper because both begin with the data "Operacional". See the ArrayLists in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should change the order of your if statements to start with the largest list :

```
        if (result.containsAll(NIVELACESSOAdmFinOper)) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter the screen Operacional - Financeiro - Administrativo");
        }

        else if(result.containsAll(NIVELACESSOOperFin)) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter the screen Operacional - Financeiro");
        }

        else if (result.containsAll(NIVELACESSOOper)) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter the screen Operacional");
        }
```

That said, your `result` list can only contain a single element, so only `result.containsAll(NIVELACESSOOper)` can return true.

I'm not entirely sure what data you are reading from the DB, since the names are not in English, but if you expect multiple rows, you should change your code to :

```
    while (rs.next()) { //Se existe registro no banco de dados com os dados informados na tela de login...

        String nivelAcesso = rs.getString("nivelAcesso"); //Comparando valor de atríbuto "nivelAcesso" do banco de dados

        result.add(nivelAcesso);
    }
```

And only after processing all the rows, you check the `result` list.

Comment: You could post an example? Because already tried to do a number of ways and could not get the results I need. This code is to create restrictions for the user at login time.

The user has level access, so when he logs will read his access levels and see which system screen they can access.

Comment: @Gustavo Do you expect your sql query to return more than one row?

Comment: Exactly! Should return 2 rows!

Comment: @Gustavo In that case, try the code in my answer. First the `while (rs.next())` loop, and then the if conditions with the changed order.

Comment: Because as you can see in the code, the ArrayList NIVELACESSOOperFin has two data which are "Operacional" and "Financeiro". Same as Operational and Financial in English. These are the access levels.

When a user logs will filter what his access levels and open the System screen that he can view.

Comment: @Gustavo As I understood your code, a user can either have only operational permission or have both operational and financial permissions or have 3 permissions - operational, financial and admin. Now, since a user can have multiple permissions, you have to read the ResultSet with a loop. And after you put the data in the `result` list, you want to check first if the user has all 3 permissions, if not, check if they have 2 permissions, and if not, check if they have one permission.

Comment: One more thing ... If the data that the user types are not registered must report a message: User or password incorrect!

I used it but it's not working: if {(!(rs.next ()))

Comment: @Gustavo Why not use `if (result.isEmpty())` after the while loop?

Comment: I can not access the option .isEmpty()

Comment: @Gustavo Note that it's `result.isEmpty()`, not `rs.isEmpty()`. `List` has an `isEmpty` method.

Comment: Sorry @Eran. Had confused the variable name... It all worked, thanks again.